# How do I select a particular dynamic div, using Selenium when I don't have a unique id or name?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Only the content of the div is unique. So, in the following dynamically generated html, only "My Article-1245" is unique:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 article">
 <h2>
      My Article-1245
     <a href="delete/6" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger article-btn pull-right hide fade in">Delete</a>
     <a href="edit/6" class="btn btn-xs btn-info article-btn pull-right hide fade in">Edit</a>
 </h2>
     <p>O ephemeral text! Here today, gone tomorrow. Not terribly important, but necessary</p>
 </div>
```

How do I select the edit/delete link of this specific div, using Selenium? `assertText/verifyText` requires an element locator, but I do not have any unique id/name (out of my control). There will be many such div blocks, with other content text, all dynamically generated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is class="col-md-4 article" is also dynamically generating

Comment: No. But that class is the same for all the articles on the page. So, there are multiple such divs, all with the same class.

Comment: and one more question href="delete/6" will remain same for the link

Comment: No, they're generated when a user enters an article (say). So, this particular div will always have "edit/6" and "delete/6", but while creating an article automatically, there's no way of knowing what the number will be.

Comment: ho ho sorry for your waste of time..me too out of thoughts...I thought i can do it by using css selector but now it seems to be can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If text 'My Article' appears each time, you may use following:

```
//For Delete
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'My Article-')]/a[text()='Delete']"));
//For Edit
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'My Article-')]/a[text()='Edit']"));
```

Hope it meets your requirement :)

Comment: Would I be able to use a javascript variable like ${titletext} instead of 'My Article-'? This is because I want to insert multiple articles, and edit each one, using Selenium. So, I want to select a specific article like 'My Article-99' or 'My Article-43', for example.

Comment: You can use simple string variable which you may keep in an array, and  use each to post the articles and later use same to generate xpath. Illustration: **//h2[contains(text(),'_"+YourVar+"_')]/a[text()='Delete']**

Comment: I tried this, but it always selects the first h2, instead of the last one. Probably because 'contains' matches even partial strings. Is there a way to ensure an exact match?

Comment: //h2[text()='"+YourVar+"']/a[text()='Delete']

Answer (score 1):

Matching by text is always a bad automated testing concept.  If you want to keep clean and reliable test scripts, then :

1. Contact your web dev to add unique identifiers to the elements
2. Suck it up, and create selectors based on what's there.

You are able to create a CSS selector based on what you want.

What you should do is create the selector using parent-child relationships:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.article:nth-child(X) a[href^='delete']"));
```

As I am ignorant of your appp, this is also assuming that all of your `article` classes are under the same parent. You would substitute `X` with the number of the div you want to refer to. e.g.:

```
<div id="someparent">
  <div class="...article" />
  <div class="...article" />
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: +1, absolutely correct. Locating by text should always be the one of last options (okay but discouraged). If someone wants to do the automation right, change the source code please.